# Vertical Mouse with Stepless Scroll Wheel

Tags: mice, ergonomics

I am looking for a vertical mouse that also has a step-less or free swinging scroll where, which works similar like the ones from the Logitech G-Series mice, where you have a button to unlock the scroll wheel, so that you can scroll a long way by just swinging the scroll wheel once.

I looked through tons of vertical mice online but did not encounter one with such an unlockable scroll wheel.

Do you know of any such vertical mouse?

Comment: Would it be safe to assume you have no price restriction?

Comment: yes, that is right.

Comment: I second this question, since I am looking for the same since over a year now. And I want to have it with cable connection.

Comment: FWIW that kind of scroll wheel with the lock is exclusive to Logitech mice, I'm pretty sure they have a patent on it. I have never seen another brand of mouse with a lock on its scroll wheel like that. The "hyperscroll" wheel from Logitech probably uses an actual encoder to detect rotations as its spinning very fast, which is expensive and unlikely to be used in most mice. As for the wheel itself spinning freely, that's also extremely unusual because scrolling isn't analog, it's digital like key presses, so the notched rotation is there to make the wheel user friendly.

Comment: Can confirm the "hyperscroll" wheel is likely exclusive to Logitech, and, it seems (from the minimal info on their website) their current two vertical mice (the "Lift" and "MX Vertical") do not have this feature. The Ergo Trackball doesn't either... the button is for switching computers, not wheel modes.

Comment: [Here on reddit](http://reddit.com/r/MouseReview/comments/5u8ggp) they also mention non-logitech mice with free spinning scroll wheel (Sensei 310 e.g.) -- but I haven't checked it out since they also are non-vertical